# Classic asp web pages no longer working after Microsoft Patch

Tags: javascript, windows-server, windows-server-2016

Earlier this week, Microsoft patch 'windows-10-update-kb4338814' got installed on our Windows Server 2016 64-bit web server. Now our web application (classic asp web pages) are not working. They are throwing `'HTTP 500 Internal Server Error'`. 
If we uninstall this KB4338814 then everything works fine. We are using IE (Version 11.2363.14393.0) and IIS Version 10.0.14393.0. 
Some of our clients are seeing the same issue. We have told them to uninstall KB patch as a workaround for now.

Looks like following line:

```
<%@Language="JavaScript"%>
```

is not working, not setting the language and as a result, all JavaScript code in the asp page is being used/treated as VBScript code and that is causing the page to fail.

If we remove `<%@Language="JavaScript"%>` line or just the `@` character, change all `<%`, `%>` to `<script>`, `</script>` then page comes up but not really functioning. That seems to indicate that this KB patch somehow interfering with the ASP setup on the server.

How can we force the JavaScript as the language in these pages after this patch? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you forgot to include the offending like?

Comment: brandones, I was not able to follow your comment. 'offending like'? Can you please expand on that? Thanks

Comment: Whoops, typo, should have been "offending line," sorry. It's there now: `<%@Language="JavaScript"%>`